Why do I get false when I use containsLocation and isLocationOnEdge in Google map
Using the Polyline method, I am trying to draw a polyline on Google Maps on a Desktop environment using the Google Map API. If I click or get a mouseover on a line then I would like to show a dialog where it will show the name of the line. I get both the mouseover and click events in my application when I click on the line. But I can't iterate because the API returns false. Could you give me a tip, about what I am doing wrong? Here is the code. I want to show the name property on the dialog. Thank you.
var g_infoWindow;
var g_curvePathArray;
var g_curvePathObjects = {};
var g_pathArray = [];
var g_pathObjects = {};

g_pathObjects['pipesegment_103'] = {
"coordinates": [
    { lat: 61.31904092678181, lng: 24.858185804137534 },
    { lat: 61.31913616518112, lng: 24.857952505746248 },
    { lat: 61.319173741447855, lng: 24.857381278784956 }
],
strokeColor: g_pipeFillColorNormal,
blockedAlarm: false,
postsuction: false,
suction: false,
name: "pipesegment_103"
};

g_pathObjects['pipesegment_49'] = {
"coordinates": [
    { lat: 61.319173741447855, lng: 24.857381278784956 },
    { lat: 61.318964199094346, lng: 24.856899615641428 }
],
strokeColor: g_pipeFillColorNormal,
blockedAlarm: false,
postsuction: false,
suction: false,
name: "pipesegment_49"
};

g_pathObjects['pipesegment_52'] = {
"coordinates": [

    { lat: 61.318964199094346, lng: 24.856899615641428 },
    { lat: 61.31897482431248, lng: 24.856266614313913 }
],
strokeColor: g_pipeFillColorNormal,
blockedAlarm: false,
postsuction: false,
suction: false,
name: "pipesegment_52"
};


for (var singlePath in g_pathObjects) {
    var populationOptions = {
    path: g_pathObjects[singlePath].coordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: g_pathObjects[singlePath].strokeColor,
    strokeOpacity: .8,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    name: g_pathObjects[singlePath].name
};

var myownpath = new google.maps.Polyline(populationOptions);
myownpath.setMap(g_map)
g_pathArray.push(myownpath);
google.maps.event.addListener(myownpath, 'click', function (e) {
    var locs = { lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng() };
    var myPosition1 = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());

    for (var i = 0; i < g_pathArray.length; i++) {
        let b = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(myPosition1, g_pathArray[i]);

        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition1, g_pathArray[i], 0.0)) {
            g_infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: myownpath.name,
            });
            console.log('index isLocationOnEdge= ' + i);
            g_infoWindow.setPosition(locs);
            g_infoWindow.open(g_map);
            break;
        }
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myownpath, 'mouseoverr', function (e) {
    var locs = { lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng() };
    var myPosition1 = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
    for (var i = 0; i < g_pathArray.length; i++) {
        let b = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, g_pathArray[i]);
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition1, g_pathArray[i])) {
            g_infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: g_pathArray[i].name,
            });
            g_infoWindow.setPosition(locs);
            g_infoWindow.open(g_map);
            break;
        }
    }

Thank you!

Why do you have the tolerance set to 0.0 for isLocationOnEdge?

Ref: containsLocation(point, polygon) you are apparently not passing a Polygon.

If I change it to if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition1, g_pathArray[i], 1e-1)) {, an InfoWindow pops up when I click on the line proof of concept fiddle

I tried other values but that did not help, anyway, that is an optional parameter.

You are  facing this issue because you have used google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation and google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge methods in you code but these are meant for checking polygons and not polylines.
I will recommend you to switch from using containsLocation to focusing on isLocationOnEdge, as will work for polylines with little bit of settings.
Also, I can see that there is one typing mistake present in you code i.e "mouseverr", change it to "mouseover".


var g_infoWindow;
var g_pathArray = [];
var g_pathObjects = {};

g_pathObjects['pipesegment_103'] = {
  "coordinates": [{
      lat: 61.31904092678181,
      lng: 24.858185804137534
    },
    {
      lat: 61.31913616518112,
      lng: 24.857952505746248
    },
    {
      lat: 61.319173741447855,
      lng: 24.857381278784956
    }
  ],
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  name: "pipesegment_103"
};

g_pathObjects['pipesegment_49'] = {
  "coordinates": [{
      lat: 61.319173741447855,
      lng: 24.857381278784956
    },
    {
      lat: 61.318964199094346,
      lng: 24.856899615641428
    }
  ],
  strokeColor: '#00FF00',
  name: "pipesegment_49"
};

g_pathObjects['pipesegment_52'] = {
  "coordinates": [{
      lat: 61.318964199094346,
      lng: 24.856899615641428
    },
    {
      lat: 61.31897482431248,
      lng: 24.856266614313913
    }
  ],
  strokeColor: '#0000FF',
  name: "pipesegment_52"
};

function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 61.31904092678181,
      lng: 24.857952505746248
    },
    zoom: 15
  };

  var g_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  for (var singlePath in g_pathObjects) {
    var populationOptions = {
      path: g_pathObjects[singlePath].coordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: g_pathObjects[singlePath].strokeColor,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      name: g_pathObjects[singlePath].name
    };

    var myownpath = new google.maps.Polyline(populationOptions);
    myownpath.setMap(g_map);
    g_pathArray.push(myownpath);

    google.maps.event.addListener(myownpath, 'click', function(e) {
      var locs = {
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng()
      };
      var myPosition1 = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());

      for (var i = 0; i < g_pathArray.length; i++) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition1, g_pathArray[i], 0.00001)) {
          g_infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: g_pathObjects[singlePath].name
          });
          g_infoWindow.setPosition(locs);
          g_infoWindow.open(g_map);
          break;
        }
      }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(myownpath, 'mouseover', function(e) {
      var locs = {
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng()
      };
      var myPosition1 = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());

      for (var i = 0; i < g_pathArray.length; i++) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition1, g_pathArray[i], 0.00001)) {
          g_infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: g_pathObjects[singlePath].name
          });
          g_infoWindow.setPosition(locs);
          g_infoWindow.open(g_map);
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
#map {
  height: 150px;
}
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap&loading=async"></script>



Use your own API Key.

Please learn how to create Stack snippets to provide runnable code in your answers. As a side note, creating a new InfoWindow object at each mouseover is most likely not a good idea. Create once and reuse with setContent() method to update content.

Thanks, Prabhat, I was using mouseverr to avoid the event (kind of commented out).  I shall test the code you have provided.

Thanks, Prabhat for the tips. It solved my problem.

That sounds good to hear....Happy Coding @RotatingWheel
